# Should the subjunctive be used when describing a hypothetical object or idea?

Tags: subjuntivo

My grammar books don't seem to provide an answer to the question of if it's correct to use subjunctive to describe hypothetical or not-yet-existent objects or ideas.  For example:

Mis libros de gramática no se parecen decir si es correcto usar el subjuntivo para describir cosas o ideas hipoteticas o aún no existentes.  Por ejemplo:

> Sugiero que hagas una herramienta que **pueda/puede** resolver el problema.

Or/O

> Sugiero que desarrolles una vista en la cual los usarios **puedan/pueden** ver sus datos personales.

Is subjunctive used in situations like these?

Se usa el subjuntivo en situaciones como estas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sí, puedes usar el subjuntivo en esos casos, tanto presente como pretérito:

> Sugiero que hagas una herramienta que **pueda** resolver el problema (o que *resuelva* el problema).
>
> Nos vendría bien tener una herramienta que **pudiese** resolver el problema (o *resolviese* el problema).

El subjuntivo se usa para expresar probabilidad y duda. Date cuenta de que lo que quieres describir es una situación hipotética en la que existe o se ha realizado una cierta idea u objeto, y quieres reflejar la posibilidad de que esa idea/objeto/etc. tenga ciertas propiedades, así puedes usar el subjuntivo para reflejar ese matiz de probabilidad y duda.